# Worklight: multiple security realms

Tags: security, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to know can we have multiple security tests defined in the `authenticationconfig.xml` file?

Will it work fine, or cause problems?

Sort of like this:

```
 <securityTests>
          <mobileSecurityTest name="myMobileSecurity">
                <testUser realm="myAppRealm"/>
                <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
            </mobileSecurityTest>
            <customSecurityTest name="PushApplication-custom-securityTest">                             
                    <test realm="PushAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true" />   
                </customSecurityTest> 
            <customSecurityTest name="myAppSecurityTestCustom">                             
                    <test realm="myAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true" />   
                </customSecurityTest> 
        </securityTests>

    <realms>
            <realm loginModule="abcModule" name="myAppRealm">
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
                <parameter name="login-page" value="login.html" />
            </realm>
            <realm loginModule="PushAppLoginModule" name="PushAppRealm">                                                
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.BasicAuthenticator</className>   
                    <parameter name="basic-realm-name" value="PushAppRealm"/>                                                  
            </realm>
            <realm loginModule="requireLogin" name="WorklightConsole">
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
                <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
            </realm>
    </realms>

    <loginModules>
             <loginModule name="PushAppLoginModule">
                <className>com.abc.MyCustomLoginModule</className>
            </loginModule>
            <loginModule name="abcModule">
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
            </loginModule>

            <loginModule name="requireLogin">
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
            </loginModule>
    </loginModules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Though I do not see the purpose of doing so...

Tip: [Understanding the Pre-defined Authentication Realms and Security Tests in Worklight](http://goworklight.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/understanding-worklight-authentication-realms-and-security-tests/)

Comment: Thanks Idan. one mobile test is for device securities, other two custom tests are for; Push security and general adapters protections. using these i have tried to protect all resources from device-based or browser based attacks.