# MobileFirst : multiple securityTests with same name allowed in v7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

One of my team member came to me and shown that he has used ***two security tests*** with the `exactly same names` and the `Studio is not giving any exception`.

- MobileFirst v7.0
- Eclipse Luna R2 (4.4.2)
- Windows 8

Here is the extract.

```
<securityTests> 
       <customSecurityTest name="MySecurityTest">               
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" /> 
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" />
            <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
              <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="1" />  
        <test realm="AdapterAuthRealmDuplicate" isInternalUserID="true" step="2" /> 
       </customSecurityTest>   

    <customSecurityTest name="MySecurityTest">              
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" /> 
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" />
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>              
        <test realm="AdapterAuthRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="2" /> 
    </customSecurityTest>
</securityTests>

<realms>                    
       <realm loginModule="AdapterAuthLoginModule" name="AdapterAuthRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="Mydapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="Mydapter.onLogout"/>
       </realm>

       <realm loginModule="AdapterAuthLoginModule" name="AdapterAuthRealmDuplicate">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="Mydapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="Mydapter.onLogout"/>
       </realm>
</realms>
```

**My question is:**

- Is this okay? keeping in mind the future compatibilities ?
- If multiples are allowed, then how they work i.e. how the challenge handlers
  execution flow (steps) goes.
- Does it combine both together ?

I think it *should not allow* two security tests with same names.

Please help me understand this, otherwise I would change it or keep it.

Note:- I had asked one question and this is different question.
[Worklight: multiple security realms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416461/worklight-multiple-security-realms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the same as realms. It should not be allowed.
I will open a defect to handle this.

Do not create two custom security checks with the same name value.